# What is the right Java collection to use in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, collections

I need to hold a large number of elements (500k or so) in a list or a set I need to do high performance traversal, addition and removal. This will be done in a multithreaded environment and I don't care if I gets to see the updates done after traversal began (weakly consistent), what Java collection is right for this scenario?

Comment: Do addition and removal happen during traversal or always at the beginning/end? Does it happen during each traversal?

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt, that's a very nice remark

Comment: One or many threads can add/remove elements while other threads are going over the collection. that's why I need a weakly consistent collection.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to hold a large number of
>   elements (500k or so) in a list or a
>   set I need to do high performance
>   traversal, addition and removal.
>   ...
>   This will be done in a multithreaded
>   environment

---

**ConcrrentSkipListMap** - it's not a List but List semantics are practically useless in concurrent environment. 
It will have the elements sorted in a tree alike structure and not accessible via hashing, so you need some natural ordering (or external via comparator)

If you need only add/remove at the ends of a Queue - **ConcurrentLinkedQueue**.

Synchronized collections are not suited for multi-threaded environment if you expect even moderate contention. They require full lock holding during the entire traverse operation as well. I'd advise against ConcurrentHashMap, either.

In the end: if you are going for real multi-CPU like 64+ and expect high contention and don't want natural ordering follow the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib

Comment: How about a Set backed by a ConcurrentHashMap, why your against ConcurrentHashMap in this situation.Ex. Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Boolean>());

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very good article on selecting a collection depending on your application

http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3829891/Selecting-the-Best-Java-Collection-Class-for-Your-Application.htm

you can try this as well

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/how_to_choose.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If traversal == read, and add/remove == update, I'd say that it's not often that a single collection is optimized for both operations.

But your best bet is likely to be a [HashMap](http://www.fromdev.com/2008/05/java-collections-questions.html#BigONotationJavaCollections).

Comment: HashMap is *bad* for traversal

Comment: Like I said, nothing is optimal.

Comment: java.util.HashMap (baring it's not thread safe) is just bad for traversal, it's worse than traversing a linked list, which has very poor (CPU) caching characteristics [nowadays a lot of algorithms performance is governed by how cache-miss prone they are]. LinkedHashMap is a bit better in that regard but also thread unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreaded - so look at j.u.concurrent. Maybe ConcurrentHashMap used as a Set - e.g. use put(x, x) instead of add(x).

Answer (score 1):

If you do addition and removal often, then something "linked" is probably the best choice. That way everytime you add/remove only an index has to be updated, in contrast to an ArrayList for example where the whole Array has to be "moved". The problem is that you are asking for the holy grail of Collections.

Taking a look at [the Concurrent Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html) might help.

But what do you mean by "traversal"?

Comment: Beware of accessing such a collection by it's index though.

Comment: Traversal is going over the elements of a collection (like in foreach loops for example) in my situation during traversal I don't modify the collection. ArrayList won't work because they need to be synchronized when accessed from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add or remove items in the middle of a list quickly, LinkedList is a good choice. To use it in multithreaded enviroment, you need to synchronise it like this:

```
List l = Collections.synchronisedList(new LinkedList());
```

Comment: you cannot traverse it unless you synchronize the entire traverse which for 500k and almost guaranteed cache-miss on each Node is just a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

On other hand, due to large size of data, is it possible to store the data in database? And use memory collection as cache.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I don't understand how this solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

are duplicate items allowed?

is yes, Set can't be used. you can use SortedSet otherwise.

Comment: Sorting the elements will have a negative impact on add/delete. And order is not required here.